# CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding. Consider adding the following to ~/.profile: export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio

I am having a rather weird day. I get this error whenever I try to run my app on iOS simulator from Android Studio

> WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8
> encoding. Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
>
> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

At this point on Xcode, I begin to get the error

> Error: "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock..."

when I try to build on Xcode. However, I am able to build successfully on Xcode and run on my emulator after the following fixes

```
 1. $pod deintegrate --verbose
 2. $pod install --verbose
```

Going back to Android Studio, I get my initial error again and so I keep going in circles

> flutter doctor Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor
> -v): [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-NG) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android
> devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and
> macOS [✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable
> at /Applications/Google
> Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
> ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable. [!] Android Studio
> ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version. [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1) [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2.1) [✓] Connected device (1 available)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just change your cocoapos version to 1.10.2 to solve your problem.

first uninstall your current version (whatever it is)

In my case, i downgraded from version 1.11.1

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then just install the stable version (as of Nov 11, 2021)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods:1.10.2
```

and build your app again.

If still not working , delete the below from the build directory:

- Podfile
- Podfile.lock
- Pods (directory)

and build.

It fixed it for me, twice in the last few days.

Comment: you saved may life

Answer (score 5):

**Solving Cocoapods UTF-8 error: (Detailed explanation)**

We need to change the locale of the terminal to UTF-8.

Step 1: Open the terminal, type locale, press enter, and check what locale it shows.

Step 2: If it's a bash terminal, change it to a zsh terminal,

Step 3: Then open finder, go to mac HD, users, folder with your username, and press command+shift+. to open hidden files

Step 4: Create or open a file named .zshrc

Step 5: Paste this there:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Step 6: Save it by command + s

Step 7: Then open the terminal again and check by typing, locale and pressing enter (Then you can either keep it open or close the terminal)

Step 8: If it shows some other locale instead of UTF-8, then paste the below 3 lines and press enter:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Step 9: Then open Android Studio, go to the terminal and paste the same above 3 lines, and press enter

Step 10: Then on your project file, go to the ios folder, right-click on it, and open in the terminal, then in the terminal, do paste the same above 3 lines and press enter

Step 11: Now you can install pods in this terminal by typing, pod install.

Now it will work, if you still get the same error, go to tools -> flutter -> flutter clean and restart android studio by clicking on File -> restart ide or a similar one.

Then on your project, right-click on the ios folder and open the terminal, type locale, and press enter, if it's not in UTF-8 now, then from step 9 again up to step 11, it will work now. You can run your app on iOS devices now.

My repo -> https://github.com/anantha-eswar/

Comment: This only worked for me when I added quotes, so `"en_US.UTF-8"`, not `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

After trying every solution I could lay my hands on, I figured it was a problem with Android studio and I fixed by completely uninstalling and reinstalling AS

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue and just fixed by downgrading the version of cocoapods to 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fish shell, do the following:

1. Open `config.fish` in the the `.config/fish/` directory
2. Add the following command

```
set -Ux LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

3. Call `source config.fish` to apply changes. Or open a new tab.

That's all. It works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything to no avail, I discovered that you need to surround the `en_US.UTF-8` in ***QUOTES***, so:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```